# How to calculate this sum like Gauss sum.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I would like to calculate the following sum, which looks like a Gauss sum.

Let $n$ be a natural number and let $a,b$ be integers. Denote by $e(x)=e^{2\pi i x/n}$. Consider the sum
$$ \sum_{1 \leq j, k \leq n} e(aj^2+2jk+bk^2).$$

I tried to calculate this sum by reducing this to the normal Gauss sum as follows. By completing square the exponent, we have
$$aj^2+2jk+bk^2=a(j+\frac{k}{a})^2+(b-\frac{1}{a})k^2.$$ Thus the sum is equal to
$$\sum_{k=1}^ne \left((b-\frac{1}{a})k^2 \right)\sum_{j=1}^n e\left(a(j+\frac{k}{a})^2\right).$$
Now this looks pretty much like a quadratic Gauss sum except that $j+\frac{k}{a}$ and $b-\frac{1}{a}$ might not be integers.

Could you give me advise how to calculate this sum?

Comment: What is the rol of $\;x\;$ in that definition of yours $\;e(x)\;$ ? An integer, I presume?

Comment: @Timbuc thank you for pointing out this. $x$ can be rational number, so the description that $e(x)$ is an $n$-th root of unity was wrong and deleted.

Comment: What do we know about the factorization of $n$? Are we free to assume $\gcd(a,n)=1$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I do not assume that but if you can calculate something by assuming the condition, I would like to know how.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\gcd(a,n)=1$. Define $c$ by $ac\equiv1\bmod n$. Then $$aj^2+2jk+bk^2=a(j^2+2cjk+bck^2)=a((j+ck)^2+(bc-c^2)k^2)$$ so the sum is $$\sum_ke(a(bc-c^2)k^2)\sum_je(a(j+ck)^2)$$ This solves your problem about things not being integers.